# ElasticSearch dynamic scripting - Groovy

Tags: elasticsearch

Does ElasticSearch dynamic scripting only apply to results that match the  should query or are all documents parsed to apply the updated _score?

Comment: i think to answer the question you should post your query, because it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the function_score wasn't boosting/burying docs since they weren't included in the query. To get around this I added "should" queries whenever I was boosting docs that might not exist (for example: boosting a taxonomy whenever a keyword was used)